# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UPDATE'

Tags: sql, sql-server

Have the following procedure and get syntax error at Update:

```
USE [OTIDatabaseNewOutreach_V3.2.0_BESQL]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[usp_OTIDataImportConstruction_U]    Script Date: 5/12/2016 8:44:18 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_OTIDataImportConstruction_U]

    UPDATE dbo.[OTI Trainer Data Import]  
    SET [Construction Industry Card #] = IsNull([c_cardnumberissued],[TrainerIDNumber]),
        [Construction Date Issued] = [tblCourse].[c_enddate]
    from tblCourse
    inner JOIN dbo.tblCourseToStudent ON dbo.tblCourse.c_id = dbo.tblCourseToStudent.c_id 
    INNER JOIN
            dbo.[OTI Trainer Data Import] ON dbo.tblCourseToStudent.t_id = dbo.[OTI Trainer Data Import].t_id
    WHERE (c_program ='construction') AND (c_expdate>GetDate());

go
```

......................................................................                                                .

Answer (score 4):

Looks like SQL Server. You need an `as` after the `create procedure`. See the manual: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-za/library/ms187926.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
USE [OTIDatabaseNewOutreach_V3.2.0_BESQL] GO /****** Object: StoredProcedure [dbo].[usp_OTIDataImportConstruction_U] Script Date: 5/12/2016 8:44:18 AM ******/ SET ANSI_NULLS ON GO SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_OTIDataImportConstruction_U] 
AS
BEGIN

UPDATE dbo.[OTI Trainer Data Import]  
    SET [Construction Industry Card #] = IsNull([c_cardnumberissued],[TrainerIDNumber]),
        [Construction Date Issued] = [tblCourse].[c_enddate]
    from tblCourse
        inner JOIN dbo.tblCourseToStudent ON dbo.tblCourse.c_id = dbo.tblCourseToStudent.c_id INNER JOIN
            dbo.[OTI Trainer Data Import] ON dbo.tblCourseToStudent.t_id = dbo.[OTI Trainer Data Import].t_id
    WHERE (c_program ='construction') AND (c_expdate>GetDate());

END
GO
```

Comment: `BEGIN` and `END` are optional

Comment: @SeanCoetzee good point, just included them as they are what is created  with the generic template from SSMS